# jsonb_populate_record / jsonb_populate_recordset should return a table

Tags: postgresql

currently I try to make a history table based on postgresql jsonb, currently as a example I have two table's:

```
CREATE TABLE data (id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, price NUMERIC(10,4) NOT NULL, article TEXT NOT NULL, quantity BIGINT NOT NULL, lose BIGINT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE data_history (id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, data JSONB NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL);
```

The history table act's a simple history (the username there could be avoided).
I populate the data of the history with a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_history() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN

    INSERT INTO data_history (data, username) VALUES (row_to_json(NEW.*), NEW.username);
    RETURN NEW;

  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now I try to populate the history back to the data table:

```
SELECT jsonb_populate_record(NULL::data, data) FROM data_history;
```

However the result will now be a tuple and not a table:

```
        jsonb_populate_record        
-------------------------------------
 (1,45.4500,0A45477,100,1,c.schmitt)
 (2,5.4500,0A45477,100,1,c.schmitt)
(2 rows)
```

Is there any way to get the data back as the `table data` back? I know there is jsonb_populate_recordset, too, however it doesn't accept a query?!

Comment: Since it returns a row-type, use it in the FROM clause, like `SELECT r.* FROM data_history, jsonb_populate_record(NULL::data, data) r`

Comment: wow thanks, could you create a answer for that so that I could give you some points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`jsonb_populate_record()` returns a row-type (or record-type), so if you use it in the `SELECT` cluase, you'll get a single column, which is a row-type.

To avoid this, use it in the `FROM` clause instead (with an implicit `LATERAL JOIN`):

```
SELECT r.*
FROM   data_history,
       jsonb_populate_record(NULL::data, data) r
```

Technically, the statement below could work too

```
-- DO NOT use, just for illustration
SELECT jsonb_populate_record(NULL::data, data).*
FROM   data_history
```

but it will call `jsonb_populate_record()` for each column in `data` (as a result of an engine limitation).